# Is it possible to access getVal() function inside displayMsg() function?

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

Is it possible to access the getVal() function inside displayMsg () function?
   I tried to create an annonymous inner-class with function getVal() and I want to call the         getVal() function inside the displayMsg() function of the AnonymousClass.

```
import java.io.*;
class AnonymousClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        displayMsg(new AnonymouseEx(10){
            public int getVal(){
                return getValue();
            }
        });

    }
    static void displayMsg(AnonymouseEx obj)
    {

    }
}
class AnonymouseEx{
    private int i=0;
    AnonymouseEx(int val)
    {
        i = val;
    }
    int getValue()
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. Have you tested ?

Comment: yes but I could access getVal() inside displayMsg() function it giving me an error.How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible.

`displayMsg` expects a class of type `AnonymouseEx` which does not have a method called `getVal`. Because you only added this function to your anonymous subclass, other subclasses might not have this function, so `displayMsg` can not use it.

If you want to give a custom implementation used in an anonymous class, you have override a function in `AnonymouseEx`  or give it an abstract method that subclasses must implement. Using the abstract method (or an interface) is most common, for instance in the `Listener` interfaces that Java uses.